# Keep getting login requests for ASP.NET app running in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7.5

When I try to access an Intranet site from a client I get asked to login all the time.
Then I get a 401.3 error. The site works fine locally on the server.

The site has its own app pool, Managed Pipeline Mode is Integrated.
I have set Read/Execute, List and Read permissions on the root web directory for the IIS_IUSRS group.
Identity impersonate is false.
Anonymous and Windows Authentication are enabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: Update: I can access the site using the IP but not by name. Not sure what this means atm though.

Comment: Does it work if you give Everyone read/write/execute on the root level?

Comment: No, I get 401.1 error, actually I'm getting that error all the time now instead of 401.3

Comment: This needs to be moved to ServerFault.  It's a configuration problem.

Comment: Update: If I change the App Pool Identity to NetworkService all is good. This could mean its a file system permissions issue. Though as explained earlier I have granted permissions to the app pool user account.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that anonymous identity is set to the proper user (one included in the IIS_IUSRS group). I would also try disabling windows authentication to see if the problem persists, I've had issues before on intranet webpages when it would prefer the windows authentication firsthand even with anonymous authentication enabled.

In case the client you are using to access the webpage has a valid domain user that is allowed to access the webpage, make sure the users password isn't expired.

Comment: The anonymous identity is set to IUSR. Disabling Windows authentication gives me a 401.3 error straight away.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the right default document set up. If IIS can't find the default document it falls back to directory browsing which you probably have disabled.

Also make sure you run:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe /i
```

From your framework folder (usually `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework(64)\v4.0...`)

Also, download [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and see what is going on on the wire.

Comment: Configuring default document and registering .NET have nothing to do with this issue. Fiddler is mostly moot since the response codes are being pulled from the IIS logs (i.e. 401.1).

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the permissions of directory? Since you using Windows authentication  you need to makesure the accessing user has permission to the specific directory.

This may be help you [Detecting permission issues using auditing and process monitor](http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/detecting-permission-issues-using-auditing-and-process-monitor)

Comment: Read my question again. Then change your answer.